# How can i run my GWT app with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, gwt

I get this error over and over. I tried this google code:
http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html

but I get the same error:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 45 more`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run Hibernate on App Engine:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

Comment: Thanks! But could you gave me any idea what should I do?

Comment: You can start by accepting my answer :). I do not know your requirements, but you may consider running your app on Google Compute Engine instead of App Engine.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot accept your answer. I am newbie here